# Regular expression for optional fields in Python

Tags: python, regex

I need to parse a line with regular expression with it's last two parameter being optional. I am giving you an example and the expression I have written.

exclaim and name are optional at the end.

```
x = re.compile('(?P<stop_id>\d{9})\s*(?P<admin_one>[[\x00-\x7F]{6}|\s{6}])\s*'
    '(?P<service_one>[[\x00-\x7F]{3}|\s{3])\s(?P<line_one>.{8})\s*'
    '(?P<direction_one>[[\x00-\x7F]{1}|\s{1}])\s*(?P<admin_two>[[\x00-\x7F]{6}|\s{6}])\s*'
    '(?P<service_two>[[\x00-\x7F]{3}|\s{3])\s(?P<line_two>.{8})\s*'
    '(?P<direction_two>[[\x00-\x7F]{1}|\s{1}])\s*'
    '(?P<interchange_time>[[\x00-\x7F]{3}|\s{3}])'
    '(\s+(?P<exclaim>).{1})?(\s+(?P<stop_name>.+))?')
```

and when I search the following string on it,

```
m = x.search('071124127 00006_ 022 94N      1 00006_ 022 83N      * 006  Radhuspladsen')
```

it gives following output when i do `m.groups()`

```
('071124127', '00006_', '022', '94N     ', '1', '00006_', '022', '83N     ',
 '*', '006', '  R', '', None, None)
```

I need the `exclaim` as `None` and `stop_name` as `Radhuspladsen`.
how to write `regex` for it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?P<stop_id>\d{9})\s*(?P<admin_one>[[\x00-\x7F]{6}|\s{6}])\s*(?P<service_one>[[\x00-\x7F]{3}|\s{3])\s(?P<line_one>.{8})\s*(?P<direction_one>[[\x00-\x7F]{1}|\s{1}])\s*(?P<admin_two>[[\x00-\x7F]{6}|\s{6}])\s*(?P<service_two>[[\x00-\x7F]{3}|\s{3])\s(?P<line_two>.{8})\s*(?P<direction_two>[[\x00-\x7F]{1}|\s{1}])\s*(?P<interchange_time>[[\x00-\x7F]{3}|\s{3}])(?:\s+(?P<exclaim>.{1}(?=\s)))?(?:\s*(?P<stop_name>.+))?
```

Try this.This will give you `stop_name`.The issue was `exclaim` was eating up the `spaces` so `stop_name` could not get any space to start with.I changes that to `\s*` so that it can start without space as well.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dN8sA5/14

Comment: Hey thanks, but these seems to be some problem , as exclaim always turns out to be None for the following valid inputs.
>>> m = x.search('071124127 00006_ 022 94N      1 00006_ 022 83N      * 006 !')
>>> m.groups()
('071124127', '00006_', '022', '94N     ', '1', '00006_', '022', '83N     ', '*', '006', None, '!')

Comment: @IshanBhatt http://regex101.com/r/dN8sA5/13 there seems to some spacing issue.newaz try this

Comment: One thing for sure, the exclaim token can contain only '!' or it is not there. See if that can help.

Comment: @IshanBhatt your input needs to have `3` space after `lineone`.That was missing.See the link i posted

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is for `?` at the last part ! you put the question sign out of the parenthesis so it work on `\s+` too ! put it inside and in a proper position also you must remove `.{1}` at the end of `exclaim`! sp change it to this:

```
'(\s+(?P<exclaim>))?(\s+(?P<stop_name>.+)?)'
```

Demo:http://regex101.com/r/kA8pE8/1